# Setting inclusion criteria for a one-place study?

Tags: one-place-studies

In my limited spare time I have embarked on a one-place study for my village. This has started out compiling various censuses and parish registers, and now I am in the process of creating a database of persons from the village. The goal is to create a database of the village population over time.

However, I have had some questions about who to include in the study database.

For example, there are people who are lodgers or servants on one census, and appear in no other records. Censuses are just a snapshot in time – the person may have left the village the next day. There are also people who appear in one baptism or marriage record in the village, but never again. I have the additional difficulty that the parish boundaries have changed over the years; the civil parish now includes several villages and hamlets, which again makes it difficult to know who to include.

Now I understand that it will largely come down to personal preference, but the scientist in me would like to formalise who I am to include in the study. I don't envisage this study as including everyone who happened to set foot in the village – that is simply unfeasible.

How should I go about setting my inclusion criteria? What do other one-place studies do?

Comment: I've never thought seriously about undertaking a one-place study, but I think they are a great idea.  Although many people may have set foot in your village, they may not have been recorded as doing so (which makes them easy to exclude) but I would expect that some people who only set foot in it once (or maybe may never have) could have impacted it greatly (I'm thinking of a salesman bringing plague to a village or a noble ordering reprisals against it) and should be part of it.

Comment: Although I wouldn't describe one of my side projects as a one-place study, it's very similar to what you're doing. And I'm including everybody -- especially as you can't tell what the real connection is between and individual and a place.

Comment: I think that I am with @ColeValleyGirl here I would record everyone. However, I may temper that with asking the question of why am I doing this? If this information is going to be freely available for anyone researching the village then their distant relative who was a resident in for a short period would show up. If you are doing this to break down a brick wall then excluding them may be the right thing to do.

Comment: I encourage everyone to come back and write more substantial answers. (I know I have a bad habit of answering Qs in comments.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criteria for what information to include in a one-place study varies based on personal interest and objectives. You stated that your goal is to create a database of the village population over time. It seems that you have the guide for what to include there in that one sentence. You want:

1. a database (this needs more clarification based on your objectives)
2. to cover one village
3. population (are you talking about numbers or individual names & families?)
4. over time (what years, 1801-1911 or ?)

Your goal seems pretty clear but what do you want to be able to do with the information when you have it complete, or at least started? If you just want population numbers that would determine many of the sources to include and exclude. If you are more interested in migration the source list may change and the priority order for gathering data may be very different.

My one-place study covers a whole parish and is directed toward family reconstitution. Anyone that appears in any record or source about the parish is included although I expect that many will never be connected into the family networks. Census records are a common starting point but I am working with the probate records first. One of my primary objectives is to find ways to help other family historians solve pre-census research questions.

The booklet, *One-Place Genealogy* by David Hawgood was published in 2001 but much of the information is still relevant.

*[Putting Your Ancestors in Their Place: A Guide to One-Place Studies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1906280436)* by Janet Few is only two years old. I've not seen this one yet but have high expectations.

The Society for One-Place Studies has a website at http://one-place-studies.org/ and also a Facebook page.

John Palmer's one-place study for [Wirksworth](http://www.wirksworth.org.uk/), Derbyshire, England is an example of an extensive and valuable project.

It is often critical to the success of a project to be very clear about what will **not** be done/included. This has saved my sanity at work more than once.